# Are $\mathbb{R}P^3$ and $T^1S^2$ isometric?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, projective-space, tangent-bundle

It is well-known that 3-dimensional real projective space $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is diffeomorphic to $T^1S^2$, the unit tangent bundle of the 2-sphere. However, I could not find any reference to whether these spaces are also isometric as Riemannian manifolds, where $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is given its canonical metric of constant curvature 1 (coming from its double cover by $S^3$), and $T^1 S^2$ is given the Sasaki metric. I feel like this should be true, but I am not sure.
Can anyone help? Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the curvature tensor of the Sasaki metric on $T^1S^2$?  Is it also constant curvature?  Is it Einstein?  (This isn't a rhetorical question; I have no idea what is meant by "the Sasaki metric on $T^1S^2$".)

Comment: The Sasaki metric on a tangent bundle of some manifold $M$ is defined using the natural splitting of the double tangent bundle $TTM$ into a horizontal and vertical part (using the Levi-Civita connection), both of which are isomorphic to $TM$. Using such isomorphisms, one can pull back $g$ and declare the horizontal and vertical part to be orthogonal. By "Sasaki metric on $T^1S^2$ I mean the restriction of the Sasaki metric of $TS^2$ to $T^1S^2$.

Comment: Both metrics are equivariant for the action of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$. So you only need to check it at a point.

Comment: The Sasaki metric on $T_1\mathbb{M}^2_\kappa$ is of constant curvature only for $\kappa=0,1$, in which case you get $K=0$ and $K=1/4$ respectively.  See [Klingenberg & Sasaki (1975)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/tohoku-mathematical-journal/volume-27/issue-1/On-the-tangent-sphere-bundle-of-a-2-sphere/10.2748/tmj/1178241033.full) for the original proof of $\kappa=1$ case.

Comment: @user10354138: Theorem 1 in the cited article gives the precise answer to TilBe's question - maybe you want to summarise it in an answer?

Comment: Indeed, it does. Thank you!